# Looking for Simple Python Help: Counting the Number of Vehicles in a CSV by their Fuel Type

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

[MY DATA IN EXCEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhVia.png)

[MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZysU1.png)

Hello Everyone!

I am brand new to python and have some simple data I want to separate and graph in a bar chart.

I have a data set on the cars currently being driven in California. They are separated by Year, Fuel type, Zip Code, Make, and 'Light/Heavy'.

I want to tell python to count the number of Gasoline cars, the number of diesel cars, the number of battery electric cars, etc.

How could i separate this data, and then graph it on a bar chart? I am assuming it is quite easy, but I have been learning python myself for maybe a week.

I attached the data set, as well as some code that I have so far. It is returning 'TRUE' when I tried to make subseries of the data as 'gas', 'diesel', etc. I am assuming python is just telling me "yes, it says gasoline there". I now just hope to gather all the "Gasoline"s in the 'Fuel' column, and add them all up by the number in the 'Vehicle' column.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/PYTHON/californiavehicles.csv')

print(df.head())
print(df.describe())

X = df['Fuel']
y = df['Vehicles']

gas = df[(df['Fuel']=='Gasoline','Flex-Fuel')]
diesel = df[(df['Fuel']=='Diesel and Diesel Hybrid')]
hybrid = df[(df['Fuel']=='Hybrid Gasoline', 'Plug-in Hybrid')]
electric = df[(df['Fuel']=='Battery Electric')]
```

I tried to create a subseries of the data. I haven't tried to include the numbers in 'vehicles' yet because I don't know how.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please could you paste your code into your post formatted as code.

Comment: I actually have it in CSV so I am able to read that data I just don't know how to manipulate it to tell me how many gasoline cars there are, how many diesel, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you use the built-in conveniences of pandas. Short answer is, use this line:

```
df.groupby("Fuel").sum().plot.bar()
```

Long answer with home made data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 1000

placeholder = [pd.NA]*N

types = np.random.choice(["Gasoline", "Diesel", "Hybrid", "Battery"], size=N)
nr_vehicles = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=N)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": placeholder,
        "Zip": placeholder,
        "Model year": placeholder,
        "Fuel": types,
        "Make": placeholder,
        "Duty": placeholder,
        "Vehicles": nr_vehicles
    }
)

df.groupby("Fuel").sum().plot.bar()
```

[image: plt.savefig("temp.png")]

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned it's a CSV specifically. Read in the file line by line, split the data by comma (which produces a list for the current row), then if currentrow[3] == fuel type increment your count.

Example:

```
gas_cars=0
with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        row = line.split(",")
        if row[3] == "Gasoline":
            gas_cars += int(row[6]) # num cars for that car make
        # ...
        # ...
        # ...
```

Comment: Hi! I see what you're getting at there. My data is like 1,000 times longer than that so I cant just make a list with that. I am hoping to end up with python telling me 'In your data set, there are 134,000 diesel vehicles, 1,560,600 gasoline vehicles, and 450,877 electric vehicles', which I can then graph

Comment: Check the comment again. The code is not making a list. It's parsing the data, which exactly accomplishes your task.

Comment: The '+=' has python telling me I am trying to compare an int and str, I am assuming cause 'Gasoline' and the number under vehicles "unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: `row` is a list of strings. You have to cast the output as an int if you are trying to add. Like this: `int(row[6])`

Comment: It is just returning the value in the first cell for me. The first row is indeed Gasoline and it recognizes that but just returns '14'. I want it to recognize every 'Gasoline' in the 'Fuel' column and add up the values in the 'Vehicles' column.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because the current code example iterates through the entire file line by line... Maybe you removed the for line in file code or just read a single line and that's it.